# PhpDocumentor2 output in HTML

Tags: php, phpdoc

One big question HOW to generate output in HTML using PhpDocumentor2.

Bcs it generates AST with .xml file but when i try to type command with:

```
-o HTML:frames:earthli
```

I get [RunTimeException] that -o (--output) option not found ??? Why ???

Full command:

```
phpdoc.bat -o HTML:frames:earthli -d C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AirAlliance\web -t C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dokumentacja --title Moje
```

Comment: I could be mistaken (hence comment), but aren't you just looking for --template template-name ?

Comment: use `phpdoc.bat -h` for help on the possible parameters.

Comment: C:\xampp\php\phpdoc.bat -d C:/xampp/htdocs/joobster -t C:/Users/Tomek/Desktop/a --title auth --template old-ocean BUT still no HTML output inside folder a only .xml .css .js files